# JS Error - Why unexpected token when x declared inside (var x=1)?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

While we can declare `var` inside a parentheses in such statement as below:

`for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {`

however I am not sure the reason of an **unexpected token** (in chrome) error when simply doing 
`(var x=1)`

In Firefox - `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'`

Comment: Typo here `i < 5,;` Remove the comma `,`

Comment: This is just because the parentheses following a `for` is not considered an `expression`. Using it without a context makes JS expect an expression inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `var` declaration inside a `for (…; …; …) { … }` statement, but that does not imply that you can put a `var` declaration in parenthesis anywhere. It's just not valid syntax. Notice that in `for`, the parenthesis are not optional either.